# How to unzip a zip file from the Terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules

The json code is not working on the server. It seems to me due to the fact that node.js is version 14 on Heroku. And the latest version 16. Everything starts on my local computer. It immediately gives an error. Help solve.

The error itself:

2021-11-18T18:02:54.848162+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:33
2021-11-18T18:02:54.848192+00:00 app[worker.1]:     agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
2021-11-18T18:02:54.848193+00:00 app[worker.1]:           ^^^
2021-11-18T18:02:54.848193+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-11-18T18:02:54.848193+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

Comment: help with json, what's wrong here?

Comment: Can you show us some code? It is hard to tell just from the error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

on Lunix we use : $zip myfile.zip filename
unzip: $unzip filename.zip